# AutomaticDataLossException occurrence

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

EF 5.0 is used and code first is applied.
An exception occurs when invoking a Count method.

> ```
> Cannot alter a column that is part of a key or an index. [ Index Name = PK_dbo.OtherRecords,Column = Id ]
> ```

(Id is the primary key)

```
            try 
            { 
                tableExists = context.MyRecords.Count() > 0; 
            }
            catch( System.Data.Common.DbException  ex ) 
            {
                logging stuff 
            }
```

The thing is that the exception message actually refers to a class, which is not part of the try-scope.
This message is not only logged when an existing sdf was migrated.
It is also the case when a new sdf is created from scratch.

Migration script --- mentioned in exception message:

```
                    CreateTable(
                    "dbo.OtherRecords", 
                    c => new
                        {
                            Id = c.String( nullable: false, maxLength: 128 ),
                        } )
                    .PrimaryKey( t => t.Id ).Index( t => t.Id );
```

Migration script --- class used in statement (in try scope).

```
                CreateTable(
                "dbo.MyRecords",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        SerialNumber = c.String(maxLength: 4000),
                        Location = c.String(maxLength: 4000),
                        Ticks = c.Long(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey( t => t.Id ).Index( t => t.Id);
```

How to clarify this exception?

EDIT: When `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;` is applied, then the exception above occurs.
When `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;` is applied, then another exception occurs as stated below:

`System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.AutomaticDataLossException`: Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss.

Resulting tables were compared - no data loss at all.

EDIT: Another migration code located in the same Up() method like OtherRecords.

```
                   CreateTable(
                   "dbo.DTRParts",
                   c => new
                       {
                           Id = c.Long( nullable: false, identity: true ),
                           TimestampTicks = c.Long( nullable: false ),
                           DeviceTypeId = c.String(maxLength: 4000),
                           CommandCode = c.Int( nullable: false ),
                           RequestId = c.Long( nullable: false ),
                           DataType = c.Byte( nullable: false ),
                           NumberOfParts = c.Int( nullable: false ),
                           PartNumber = c.Int( nullable: false ),
                           IsDeflated = c.Boolean( nullable: false ),
                           TraceData = c.Binary( maxLength: 8000 ),
                       } )
                   .PrimaryKey( t => t.Id ).Index( t => t.Id );
```

Can anyone explain why an AutomaticDataLossException occurs with those scripts? (It occurs also when the sdf is newly generated)

Code within Down() was commented. Thus, no data loss at this point.
And Down() is not invoked at all.

As mentioned, EF 5.0 is used (in development & production use).
Is an `AutomaticDataLossException` (e.g. for empty content / new sdf) as stated also an issue within EF 6 or higher?

Comment: If you remove the .Index() methods, does it work? PK should be automatically indexed

Comment: @Vlad274 have tried it, nope - same exception

Comment: Is that the only migration you have? Are Automatic Migrations enabled?

Comment: @Vlad274 no, another migration script exists but without a foreign key or something similar to the mentioned ones within migration scripts. yes, automatic-based.